# What is an extended partition for? Is it comes by default when Ubuntu installed via a CD?

Tags: 12.04, installation, partitioning

What an extended partition is for? Is it comes by default when Ubuntu installed via a CD? If not why I see an extended partition in my Ubuntu 12.04 OS?

Thank you.

Comment: @Radu Rădeanu. No dear that [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151968/what-does-the-term-extended-partition-mean-is-it-safe-to-use-this-type-of-par) is not an exact answer I am looking for. 1-) I do not use windows in my PC. 2) There is still no answer for my question: Is it (extended partition) comes by default when Ubuntu installed via a CD? Because I see an extented partition [link](http://imgur.com/4oVKGya)  on my PC without my knowledge. I do not know how it come.

Comment: I FOUND AN ANSWER: I found out that in partition time of your HDD (via Gparted or Live CD); if you mark the partition part as logical, it will result to create an extended partition. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The partition table has room for only four partitions. For more partitions, one of these four partitions can be divided into many smaller partitions, called logical partitions. The original four are then called primary partitions. If a primary partition is subdivided in this way, it is known as an extended primary or extended partition.

Typically, the first primary partition will be small ( /dev/hda1, say). The second primary partition will fill the rest of the disk as an extended partition ( /dev/hda2, say). In this case, the entries in the partition table of / dev/hda3 and /dev/hda4 will be blank. The extended partition can be subdivided repeatedly to give /dev/hda5, /dev/hda6, and so on.