# Cannot create a new partition for my unallocated space

Tags: installation, partitioning

Well, I had 4 primary partitions. One is for Windows system files (booting and stuff), one is for Windows files, one is for my data and one is almost empty but I store some data on as well.

I wanted to install Ubuntu 13.04 on a partition on itself and stop using Wubi as it cause some problems at booting, So I backed up my almost-empty partition, deleted it and started Ubuntu installation.

This partition is about 222 GB. I wanted to install Ubuntu only on 20 GB. So on installation I made a partition for swap files and a partition for the root directory to be installed on.

When I finished installation. I couldn't create new partition. I cannot use my other 180 GB hard disk space and it tells me that I've reached the maximum number of partitions by now.

This is a picture for Disks app.
[image: my hard disk partitions]

I know it must be a logical partition. It still refuses that.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use Gparted from a Live CD/USB, and expand the 28GB [Extended partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151968/what-does-the-term-extended-partition-mean-is-it-safe-to-use-this-type-of-par) all the way to the right. Then you should be able to create more logical partitions.