# Trying to Install Ubuntu 12.04 need help

Tags: 12.04, partitioning

I want to install ubuntu 12.04 alongside windows7 but in the ubuntu installation the option Run Alongside Windows 7 doesnt appear, and I want to know what I need to do to the partitions to do the dual/boot

Here s a screenshot of the partitions:

[image]

Comment: Duplicated of http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Close voters: that "4 primary partitions" question is, in my opinion, a very specific question and should not be used to reference all questions like these (the first answer there starts off by instructing the user to delete HP_TOOLS. If he doesn't have it, he'll be confused. The other answer instructs the user to pick a "partition they don't want", but what if they want all of them?). I'll try to post an informative answer here that can be used for reference for other cases instead of that "4 primary partitions" question.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps:

1. Boot into windows
2. Right click on computer and click on manage.
3. Select Disk Management in Storage
4. Select your DATA partition and shrink it to the amount you want to allocate to Ubuntu.
5. Right click the new space that has just showed up and click on delete volume.

Now you can boot into ubuntu live CD and use that space to install the OS.

I'm assuming you know how to manually partition the space to install the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Your partition table (provided it is MS-DOS) has already 4 primary partitions. This means that even if you shrink a volume, you cannot create a new partition to install ubuntu, because the MS-DOS partition table does not support more than 4 primary partitions. The most reasonable solution here, is to create an [extended](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151968/what-does-the-term-extended-partition-mean-is-it-safe-to-use-this-type-of-par) partition that will hold your DATA and the Ubuntu installation.