# How to combine a paritition with Ubuntu's paritition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 a few days ago on dual boot with Windows 7 (not using Wubi) and now I see that I am almost running out of space.

I used GParted on a live CD. Now, I have on my drive an unallocated partition which was an empty partition but I can't add it to the Ubuntu's partition. When I right-click the Ubuntu's partition all I can do is `Manage flags`, `Information`.

Heres is the output of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem  Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
/cow       1001M  66M  935M   7% / 
udev        990M  12K  990M   1% /dev 
tmpfs       201M 1.2M  200M   1% /run 
/dev/sr0    996M 996M     0 100% /cdrom 
/dev/loop0  953M 953M     0 100% /rofs 
none        4.0K    0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup 
tmpfs      1001M 1.3M 1000M   1% /tmp 
none        5.0M 4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock 
none       1001M  76K 1001M   1% /run/shm 
none        100M  72K  100M   1% /run/user
```

Output of `sudo parted -l`:

```
Model: ATA Hitachi HDS72103 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB  105MB   primary   ntfs            boot
 2      106MB   298GB  298GB   primary   ntfs
 3      298GB   320GB  22.2GB  extended                  lba
 5      298GB   312GB  14.0GB  logical   ntfs
 6      312GB   318GB  5961MB  logical   ext4
 7      318GB   320GB  2144MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

[image]

Comment: which partition do you refer to? all the partitions which are visible here are used for some of the linux folders. however, there are a lot of different ways (some more reliable) to show all the partitions: [http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-list-disk-partitions-command/] this would allow you to give the file system type, too. not all of them are fully supported by linux or windows

Comment: I don't understand. What should I do?
I'm very new to all of it...
Why it didn't work if I used the liveCD?

Comment: I suggest you use GParted Partition Manager to manage your disks and partitions and perhaps post a screenshot of the disk shown in GParted and then ask for suggestions.

Comment: @Sadi I use GParted.

Comment: @RodSmith I will add a screenshot and the outpot.

Comment: sudo parted -1 output:

`Model: ATA Hitachi HDS72103 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags

 1      1049kB  106MB  105MB   primary   ntfs            boot

 2      106MB   298GB  298GB   primary   ntfs

 3      298GB   320GB  22.2GB  extended                  lba

 5      298GB   312GB  14.0GB  logical   ntfs

 6      312GB   318GB  5961MB  logical   ext4

 7      318GB   320GB  2144MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
`

Comment: Iv'e added the output to the question.

and it is not a duplicate, he replaced windows 7 with ubuntu, I have both.

Comment: So you basically want to merge two partitions?  Which ones?

Comment: I don't see any significant unallocated space. (BTW, "unallocated partition" is an oxymoron; space is either allocated to a partition or unallocated.) You'll need to shrink one or more partitions to make free space, possibly move intervening partitions, and then increase the size of your Ubuntu partition. The answers to the question I linked to describe this process in more detail. (The fact that the poster of that question doesn't boot Windows any more is irrelevant; your situations are directly analogous.)

Comment: @rod smith I now have 12.99 GB of unallocated space. It's just that I can't use it for the Ubuntu's partition.    http://s1164.photobucket.com/user/itsthenoaman/media/Mobile%20Uploads/20150507_220720_zpsv7c5tiqw.jpg.html     here's a photo from gparted.  I still can't do anything to this partition.      The Ubuntu's partition is sda 3

Comment: Your gparted screen shot does not match the output of parted -l.  Did you already significantly shrink sda5 since then?

Comment: Ubuntu's partition is `/dev/sda6`, not `/dev/sda3`; `/dev/sda3` is an [extended partition](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151968/what-does-the-term-extended-partition-mean-is-it-safe-to-use-this-type-of-par) that holds (in your case) `/dev/sda5` through `/dev/sda7`. Based on your screen shot, you should be able to move and resize `/dev/sda6`.

Comment: @psusi I resized it already.

Answer (score 0):

1. As you can see in the screenshot, the extended      partition (sda3) containing your Ubuntu partition (sda6) is locked; that's why you can't do what you want.
2. To unlock the extended partition, you need to unlock the swap partition (sda6) by right clicking and selecting "swap off".
3. Then you should be able to enlarge the Ubuntu partition to the left, and it is better to include all the available space there.

Comment: Thank you, but that wasn't the problem. Rod Smith answerd it. I just didn't knew what partition to resize. I needed to resize sda 6 and I've tried sda 3.