# Is there a "Edit mount options" (cog icon) in palimpsest in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, mount, permissions, automount

EDIT: Downvoters, please explain to me what is wrong with the question, so I can improve it. Thank you.

---

I'm trying to change the default permissions of some automounted USB drives which are VFAT, and by this image:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/07/mount-partitions-automatically-ubuntu-14-04/
[image: edit-mount-options]

... I guess that I could do it from `gnome-disks`. However, this PC is:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS \n \l
```

... and so it doesn't have `gnome-disks`, it has `palimpsest` instead. So I tried opening both as regular user: `palimpsest`, and as root `gksu palimpsest`, but I get the very same screen:

[image: palimpsest]

That is - there is no cog icon anywhere, there is no "Edit Mount Options" anywhere either.

So I just wanted to make sure - does `palimpsest` in Ubuntu 12.04 have a cog-icon/"Edit Mount Options", but I have my PC misconfigured (i.e. maybe I have missing packages) - or is it incapable of changing mount options by default?

Comment: There is not, and gnome-disks is just a newer iteration of palimpsest, with a much better name.

Comment: Thanks @mikewhatever - feel free to post that as an answer, I'll accept it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, gnome-disk-utility had no edit mount option at that time. It had Edit FileSystem Label, FileSystem type etc options.

I have one 12.04 ISO still now, but I think this question's screenshot will prove it. The OP here was running 12.04 and the screenshot is from gnome-disk-utility. There was no cog icon. It was later introduced.

[What does the term "Extended Partition" mean? Is it safe to use this type of partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151968/what-does-the-term-extended-partition-mean-is-it-safe-to-use-this-type-of-par)

And the Ubuntu handbook was featuring a 14.04 gnome-disk which is different than 12.04's gnome-disk-utility