# Duplicate partition in gnome-disks

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gnome, gnome-disk-utility

I use a 525 GB drive that's dual booted with Ubuntu 18.10 and Windows 10. My Windows partition should be 425 GB and my Ubuntu partition should be 100 GB, but I see two non-NTFS entries:

- One says Extended (Contents: Extended)
- One says Linux (Contents: Ext4)

Both volumes say 100 GB, so I am confused what the difference between the two are. I'm thinking they can't be independent volumes, since then the numbers wouldn't add up to 525 GB.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/151968/what-does-the-term-extended-partition-mean-is-it-safe-to-use-this-type-of-par  You are seeing an Extended Partition with a Logical Partition (ext4) contained within.  It is not a duplicate partition but a container type to extend beyond the 4 Primary Partition limit of a MBR partitioning scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Terrance. Thank you, that gave me the information I was looking for.

An extended partition is a special container type that allows for more partitions than the maximum four allowed by a traditional partition table. It can hold multiple logical partitions. An operating system (such as Ubuntu) can be installed on either a primary or logical partition.

This installation just created an extended partition and installed on a logical partition, to allow for future partitioning if needed.